# Order columns in R based on numeric sequence

Tags: r, dplyr

I have columns:

`location, id_1, id_2, id_3, ..., id_20, name_1, name_2, name_3, ..., name_20`

I would like to reorder them to look like this:

`location, id_1, name_1, id_2, name_2, ..., id_20, name_20`

`select(location, ends_with("1"), ends_with("2"), etc.` works, but is undesirable with 20 variables.

Any idea on how to reorder the variables based on the number in the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can order on the substring on the column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df1 %>%
     select(location,   order(parse_number(names(.)[-1])) + 1)
```